# Как добавить ещё один столбец для поиска в sql

Tags: php, поиск

Нашел код на просторах интернета, который осуществляет поиск. Проблема в том, что я не могу его расширить и включить ещё один столбец, в котором будет осуществляться поиск. Там используются какие-то кавычки. Я раньше с таким не сталкивался. Помогите пожалуйста включить ещё столбец title в поиск.

```
<?php
  require 'db.php';

$query = $_POST['query'];
$mass = explode(' ', $query);
$count_mass = count($mass);

  for ($i=0; $i <$count_mass ; $i++) {
    if ($i==0) {
      $part1="`text` LIKE '%".$mass[0]."%'";
    } else {
      $part2 ="AND `text` LIKE '%".$mass[$i]."%'";
      $part1 = $part1.$part2;
    }
  }

  $result = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE".$part1."ORDER BY `id` DESC ");
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['title'];
  }
?>
```

$mass берется из поля ввода и проходит через аякс. В нем могут содержаться целые предложения для поиска. Не понимаю зачем минусить когда можно предложить помощь. Не все же кодеры являются гугл разработчиками. У меня например образование совсем не связано с программированием.

Comment: у вас есть запрос `SELECT * FROM 'articles' WHERE".$part1."ORDER BY 'id' DESC` в котором `.$part1.` обозначает условие по которому происходит поиск путём запроса. Взглянем на код чуть выше, мы видим как формируются первоначальные `$part1` и `$part2`, а затем объединяются вместе. Посмотрим что там используется в `$part2` и сразу же видим конструкцию `AND ...`. В вашем случае уместно будет создать еще одну переменную `$part3` и сложить в неё через тот же `AND <ваше условие для title>`, а затем объединить

Comment: я не совсем уверен в том какую реляционную бд вы используйте, но всё же приложу документацию по тому как можно составлять условные блоки `WHERE` -> https://sql-academy.org/ru/guide/conditional-where-operator

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код выдаст предупреждение, $part1 не объявлена перед циклом.
Увидеть бы что в переменной $mass.

```
<?php
  require 'db.php';

  $query = $_POST['query'];
  $mass = explode(' ', $query);
  $count_mass = count($mass);

  $where=array();
  for ($i=0; $i <$count_mass ; $i++) {
    if ($i==0) {
      $where[] = "`text` LIKE '%".$mass[0]."%'";
    } else {
      $where[] = "`text` LIKE '%".$mass[$i]."%'";
      $where[] = "`title` LIKE '%что_надо_найти%'";
    }
  }

  $result = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE".join(" AND ",$where)." ORDER BY `id` DESC");
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['title'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Переменная $mass получает из поля значения, которые необходимо найти в бд. Поэтому там может быть целое предложение для поиска. Я протестил Ваш вариант и, к сожалению, не смог найти title и словосочетания тоже перестали находится если их более одного

Comment: То есть в одном поле через пробел написаны какие-то значения, которые необходимо найти в БД. При этом эти значения должны содержаться и в поле *text*, и в поле *title*. Всё верно? Или значения могут быть только в поле *text*, или только в поле *title*? Или и там, и там?